# Does C++ have facilities in standard library for comparing iterator categories

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I would like to static_assert that container provided to my function have bidirectional or stronger iterator.
Only way I know how to do this is to compare that it is not one of the weaker iterators.

```
    static_assert(! std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<typename C1::iterator>::iterator_category, std::input_iterator_tag>::value,"");
    static_assert(!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<typename C1::iterator>::iterator_category, std::forward_iterator_tag>::value, "");
//TODO:add check it is not output iter....
```

Any way to say iterator_category is bidi or stronger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags inherit from each other (so random inherits from bidirectional, which inherits from forward, which inherits from input).

Therefore, you can do the following (still fairly long of course..)

`static_assert(std::is_base_of<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, typename std::iterator_traits<typename C1::iterator>::iterator_category>::value, "");`

Answer (score 0):

The five possible types of `iterator_category` are `input_iterator_tag`, `output_iterator_tag`, `forward_iterator_tag`, `bidirectional_iterator_tag`, and `random_access_iterator_tag`.

Since you're using two of them already, I assume you can use the others.